# RandomWalk.java stuck

Tags: java

I believe I've accomplished the first half of this but I'm completely stuck on what to do for the second part.

The RandomWalk class will have the following instance data (all type int):

- the x coordinate of the current position
- the y coordinate of the current position
- the maximum number of steps in the walk
- the number of steps taken so far in the walk
- the boundary of the square (a positive integer -- the x and y
  coordinates of the position can vary between plus and minus this
  value)

Create a new file RandomWalk.java. You’ll define the RandomWalk class incrementally testing each part as you go.

- First declare the instance data (as described above) and add the
  following two constructors and toString method.
- RandomWalk (int    max, int edge) - Initializes the RandomWalk
  object. The maximum    number of steps and the boundary are given by
  the parameters. The x    and y coordinates and the number of steps
  taken should be set to 0.
- RandomWalk (int max, int edge, int startX, int startY) --
  Initializes the maximum number of steps, the boundary, and the
  starting position to those given by the parameters.
- String    toString() - returns a String containing the number of
  steps taken so    far and the current position -- The string should
  look something    like: Steps: 12; Position: (-3,5)

THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK

Compile what you have so far then open the file TestWalk.java. This file will be used to test your RandomWalk
methods. So far it prompts the user to enter a boundary, a maximum number of steps, and the x and y coordinates of
 position. Add the following:

- Declare and instantiate two RandomWalk objects -- one with boundary
  5, maximum steps 10, and centered at the origin (use the two
  parameter constructor) and the other with the values entered by the
  user.
- Print out each object. Note that you won’t get any information about
  the boundary or maximum number of steps (think about what your
  toString method does), but that’s ok. Compile and run the program to
  make sure everything is correct so far.

public class RandomWalk {

```
private int startX, startY, max, stepsTaken, edge;

public RandomWalk(int max, int edge) {

startX = 0;
startY = 0;
stepsTaken = 0;
this.max = max;
this.edge = edge;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Steps: " + stepsTaken + "; " + "(" + startX + "," + startY + ")";
}
```

}

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Sounds like a nice little homework problem.  Good luck!  Oh, if you have any QUESTIONS, please ask.

Comment: Yes, it is a homework question. I'm not asking for the answer, I'm asking for a hint on what to do for the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Declare and instantiate two RandomWalk objects -- one with boundary 5, maximum steps 10, and centered at the origin (use the two parameter constructor) and the other with the values entered by the user."

This means you want to create two new objects of the RandomWalk type. And this is being done in your new file, TestWalk.java. I'm guessing there's a main/run method in there somewhere, so in there, you're gonna need some sort of declarations.

And then it says: one with boundary 5, maximum steps 10, and centered at the origin (use the two parameter constructor) and the other with the values entered by the user."

So it will look something like this:

```
RandomWalk firstObject = new RandomWalk(10, 5);
RandomWalk secondObject = new RandomWalk(something, something);
```

And then it says print them out by doing: `System.out.println(firstObject);` and then again for secondObject.